# stop windows service from within sql server

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008

I'm running maintenance plans at night on my SQL Server 2008 database for reorganizing the indexes and shrinking the database. While this plan is running a windows service that I built that queries the DB keeps failing with timeouts.

How can I stop the Windows Service from within the Maintenance Plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [xp_cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) SP to issue a `net stop <service_name>` then a `net start <service_name>`

Comment: Thanks Zypher, I was going this route, but I'm getting a System error 5 has occurred. Access Denied. Do you know in which user context do the Maintenance Plans run as?

Comment: You might need to set the proxy account, or strait out enable the SP See the remarks section (about halfway down) of my technet link for the howto

Comment: do you know which security rights I should grant the user to be able to execute the net command? Maybe I should open a new question for that

Comment: You're options are 1) (local | domain) admin or 2) Grant a user permissions by following this KB http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325349

Comment: this is very weird. Since I can't get this to work. I added the user running the SQL Server Service as part of the admin group and when I run the xp_cmdshell I still get Access is denied. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Never mind, I got it working with the proxy account and making it an Admin